# Drupal trouble installing theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes

Hello im trying to install a drupal theme,

This what I get:

WARNING: You are not using an encrypted connection, so your password will be sent in plain text. Learn more.

Then I need to provide FTP Connection settings but where do I find these settings? I have never used FTP yet..

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Drupal initially?

I assume you uploaded it to your host? What FTP details did you use then?

You need to supply the same details again now.